How to create a small image display in the corner while the original image stays unchanged in the middle?
Thanks for taking your time to listen to my problem! So I am working on a project, where I am trying to make an image editing program. So far I have followed a great guide by Clear Code. However, he doesnt go over more certain elements, like having a smaller display up in the corner displaying the original image.
I have tried doing this by implementing a new class SmallImage and function small_image which are basically cheap replica's of his which is also incoporated in the program. However, they dont seem to work as intended, I do see that a frame gets placed from the start since an outline of black appears.
Basically what I am trying to achieve is having a smaller version of the original image in the frames [5, 1] [5, 2][6, 1] [6, 2], so it covers a 2x2 area on the left side of the screen.
Another problem I encountered, is when I open an image the frames its occupying changes size, and becomes smaller, since they want to resize with the image, even though i want the image to scale to the frames size.
I am not very good at coding, so I hope someone can help :)
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import filedialog, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageOps


# COLORS

BACKGROUND = '#282828'
STROKE = '#312E2E'
PANEL_BG = '#535353'
PANELS = '#353535'

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):

        # Setup
        super().__init__()
        ctk.set_appearance_mode('dark')
        self.geometry('1000x600')
        self.title('Fuck yeah')
        self.minsize(800,500)

        # canvas data
        self.image_width = 0
        self.image_height = 0
        self.canvas_width = 0
        self.canvas_height = 0

        # layout
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = 'a')
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.rowconfigure(4, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform = 'a')
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform = 'a')
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.columnconfigure(4, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.columnconfigure(5, weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.columnconfigure(6, weight=1, uniform='a')
        FrameColor(self, color=PANEL_BG, x=0, y=0, strY=5, strX=7)
        self.image_import = ImageImport(self, self.import_image, color=BACKGROUND, x=1,y=1,strY=3,strX=4, paddingX= 10, paddingY=10)
        FrameColor(self, color=PANELS, x=0, y=0,strY=1,strX=1)
        FrameColor(self, color=PANELS, x=0, y=4, strY=1, strX=1)
        FrameColor(self, color=PANELS, x=6, y=0, strY=1, strX=1)
        FrameColor(self, color=PANELS, x=6, y=4, strY=1, strX=1)
        #self.image_import = ImageImport(self, self.import_image, color=BACKGROUND, x=5, y=1, strY=2, strX=2, paddingY=0, paddingX=0)

        self.small_image_frame = SmallImage(self, self.small_image, x=5, y=1, strX=2, strY=2)


        self.mainloop()

    def import_image(self, path):
        self.original = Image.open(path)
        self.image = self.original
        self.image_ratio = self.image.size[0] / self.image.size[1]
        self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.image_import.grid_forget()
        self.image_output = ImageOutput(self, self.resize_image)
        self.close_button = CloseOutput(self, self.Close_edit)
        #self.menu = Menu(self, self.rotate_float, self.zoom_float)

    def small_image(self, path):
        self.original = Image.open(path)
        self.image = self.original
        self.image_ratio = self.image.size[0] / self.image.size[1]
        self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.small_image_frame.grid_forget()
        self.image_output = SmallImage(self, self.resize_image,x=5,y=1,strX=2,strY=2)

    def Close_edit(self):
        # hide image and close button
        self.image_output.grid_forget()
        self.close_button.place_forget()
        #self.menu.grid_forget()
        self.image_import = ImageImport(self, self.import_image, color=BACKGROUND, x=1,y=1,strY=3,strX=4,paddingX=10,paddingY=10)

    def resize_image(self, event):
        # current canvas ratio
        canvas_ratio = event.width / event.height

        # update canvas attribute
        self.canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas_height = event.height

        # resize
        if canvas_ratio > self.image_ratio: # if canvas is wider than the image
            self.image_height = int(event.height)
            self.image_width = int(self.image_height * self.image_ratio)
        else: # if canvas is taller than the image
            self.image_width = int(event.width)
            self.image_height = int(self.image_width / self.image_ratio)

        self.place_image()

    def place_image(self):
        self.image_output.delete('all')
        resized_image = self.image.resize((self.image_width, self.image_height))
        self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
        self.image_output.create_image(self.canvas_width / 2, self.canvas_height / 2, image = self.image_tk)

class FrameColor(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent,color, x, y, strX, strY):
        super().__init__(master=parent,fg_color=color)
        self.grid(column=x, columnspan=strX, row=y, rowspan=strY, sticky='nsew')
class ImageImport(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, import_func, color, x, y, strX, strY, paddingX, paddingY):
        super().__init__(master=parent, fg_color= color)
        self.grid(column = x, columnspan = strX, row = y, rowspan=strY, padx = paddingX, pady = paddingY, sticky = 'nsew')
        self.import_func = import_func

        ctk.CTkButton(self, text='Open image', command=self.open_dialog).pack(expand=True)

    def open_dialog(self):
        path = filedialog.askopenfile().name
        self.import_func(path)

class SmallImage(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, update_func, x, y, strX, strY):
        super().__init__(master=parent, fg_color=PANEL_BG)
        self.grid(column=x, columnspan=strX, row=y, rowspan=strY, sticky='nsew')
        self.update_func = update_func
        #self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self)
        #self.label.pack(expand=True)


class ImageOutput(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, resize_image):
        super().__init__(master = parent, background= BACKGROUND, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        self.grid(row = 1, column = 1,columnspan=3,rowspan=3, sticky = 'nsew')
        self.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)

class CloseOutput(ctk.CTkButton):
    def __init__(self, parent, close_func):
        super().__init__(master=parent, command=close_func, text='x', text_color= 'white', fg_color='transparent', 
                         width=40, height=40,
                         corner_radius = 0,
                         hover_color = 'red'
                         )
        self.place(relx=0.99, rely=0.01,anchor='ne')
App()

